# An VR app developed using google vr sdk for unity with android can be used on a Lenovo Mirage Solo with Daydream?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, mirage

I am developing a VR app using google vr sdk for unity. But I have a doubt, this app could be used on a Lenovo Mirage Solo? or only on a Daydream view device?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Mirage Solo is a Daydream-compatible device, so any app developed with the Google VR SDK should work there, too.